# how to get custom date time format in sql

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to convert Date Time in Sql,

I want format like this :- `DD-MM-yyyy 00:00  (24 Hours) for example :- 12-Nov-2014 00:00`

I tried this: `CONVERT(varchar(16), IFD.dtDateOfIncident, 113) As EventDate`  , but I don't get success and I have also refer this `http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx` , but I can't find any method or keyword.

Please Help me

Regards,
Vinit

Comment: Can I ask why you need a specific format in SQL-Server itself.. Why not do it in front-end (like C#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problen with varchar(16). The varchar length must be 17 to achieve your requirement.

```
CONVERT(varchar(17), IFD.dtDateOfIncident, 113)


SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(11), IFD.dtDateOfIncident, 106) , ' ', '-') 
       + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(5), IFD.dtDateOfIncident, 108)
```

Comment: @Vap I added query for your requrement.

Answer (score 4):

```
declare @dt varchar(20) = '12-Nov-2014 24:59'

Select Replace(Convert(varchar(17),GETDATE(),106),' ','-') + ' ' + Convert( varchar(5) , GETDATE(),108)
```

Comment: `REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 106), ' ', '-')`  http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: sorry @jaugar, but what you want from my side. I think you want to show the format, then it is good link.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You can use either `13` or `113` in `Convert Function` . Increase the length of your `varchar` in `convert`

```
select convert(varchar(30),GETDATE(),113) --19 Nov 2014 11:26:46:420
select convert(varchar(30),GETDATE(),13)  --19 Nov 2014 11:26:46:420
```

**Update :**  To get `-` in `date`

```
select replace(left(convert(varchar(30),GETDATE(),113),11),' ','-')+RIGHT(convert(varchar(30),GETDATE(),113),13)
```

**Output :** `19-Nov-2014 11:32:17:890`

Comment: But There is No - in Date How can i get?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below query if U are using SQL server 2008 and above

```
select replace(convert(varchar(17),IFD.dtDateOfIncident,106), ' ','-') + ' ' + 
       Cast(convert(Time(0),GETDATE(),108) as Varchar) As EventDate
```

or

try this for SQL server 2000 and above

```
select replace(convert(varchar(17),IFD.dtDateOfIncident,106), ' ','-') + ' ' + 
       convert(Vacrhar(8),IFD.dtDateOfIncident,108) As EventDate
```

The above queries will display the reuslt like
**19-Nov-2014 11:10:45**

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this in SQL. Do it in whatever language you are using in the front end application. If your presentation layer is web, use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com)

```
moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY, HH:mm');
```

In C# you might do it like this

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")
```

Formatting for display is a presentation layer consideration.